# Como fazer para o Apache (wamp) parar de matar a sessão sozinho?

Tags: apache, session, wamp

Desenvolvi uma aplicação com `laravel` e deixei ela rodando no `wamp`, porém depois de um tempo ele acaba matando a sessão do usuário, gostaria de saber se existe alguma configuração para que ele pare de fazer isso?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precisa definir o [**session.cookie_lifetime**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) e a probabilidade de quanto % do tempo o lixo das `sessions` expiradas serão coletadas. 0% = nunca.

> session.cookie_lifetime especifica o tempo de vida do cookie em segundos que é enviado para o browser. O valor 0 significa "até o browser ser fechado".

Pode configurar no seu php.ini:

```
#definie para ficar ativo até o browser ser fechado
session.cookie_lifetime = 0

#  0 de probabilidade
session.gc_probability = 0

# 1 de divisão
session.gc_divisor = 1

# Logo o gc_maxlifetime vai ser checado 0% das vezes. (0 / 1 = 0%)
# ou seja, gc_probability / gc_divisor

# seta para ficar ativo até o browser ser fechado.
session.gc_maxlifetime = 0
```

Pode configurar direto no PHP, em tempo de execução:

```
// definie para ficar ativo até o browser ser fechado
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime', 0); 

// 0 de probabilidade
ini_set('session.gc_probability', 0);

// 1 de divisão
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1); 

// Logo o gc_maxlifetime vai ser checado 0% das vezes. 
// (0 / 1 = 0%) ou seja, gc_probability / gc_divisor

// ativo até o browser ser fechado
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 0);

// SOMENTE APÓS as configurações, abre a nova seção
session_start();
```

Comment: Vou testar, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Aparentemente funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Existe vários tipos de configurações que você pode fazer no .htacess do Apache:

```
&lt;IfModule mod_php5.c&gt;

    # Definir o tempo máximo de execucao do script para 30 mins (padrão: 60s)
    php_value max_execution_time 1800

    # Definir o tempo de expiração de sessao para 2 horas (padrão: 24 mins)
    php_value session.cookie_lifetime 7200
    php_value session.cache_expire 7200
    php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 7200

&lt;/IfModule&gt;
```

A documentação aqui: [Configuração Session](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/session.configuration.php)

Você também pode aumentar a expiração do cache da session: 
[Documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-cache-expire.php)

E uma boa leitura sobre session do PHP: [Link StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se o seu **php.ini** , tem um valor para session.gc_maxlifetime (e também session.cookie_lifetime ), que estabelece um limite de quanto tempo PHP permitirá sessões para durar.

Uma solução consiste em verificar o seu php.ini. Você pode ter essa variável definida: session.gc_maxlifetime. Por padrão, ele é definido para 1440. Apenas comentar ou excluí-lo .

Comment: Vou tentar fazer isso, para saber se deu certo terei que aguardar um tempo para ver se não mata a sessão rsrsrs.

Comment: Não funcionou :/